How to identify whether given element is meta(-ate) ion or meta(-ite) ion?
Like why $\ce{PbO3-}$ is a meta plumbate anion because definition of meta(-ate) ion is that it has maximum oxidation state of Pb by using minimum oxygens. But in this case how oxidation state of Pb is highest?

and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59302/nomenclature-of-polyatomic-ions

$\ce{PbO3^-}$? With lead(V)?
